# How to write the data to an excel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyexcel

Im writing the data inside my dictionary to an excel which looks like below

```
my_dict = { 'one': 100, 'two': 200, 'three': 300}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(), columns=['Summary','Count'])

with pd.ExcelWriter('outfile.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

for the above code im getting the desired output like below.

[image]

I have one more list which have some values which needs to be pasted in the 3rd column of the excel.

```
my_list = [10,20,30]
```

expected output:

[image]

**Edit: I need to add the data in my_dict and the my_list at the same time.**

I have tried finding out a solution unfortunately couldn't able to. Any help is appreciated!
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the data in `my_dict` and the `my_list` **at the same time** to define the dataframe `df`, you can chain the `pd.DataFrame()` call with [`.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to define the column named `my_list` using the input list `my_list` as input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(), columns=['Summary','Count']).assign(my_list=my_list)
```

Of course, the most trivial way of doing that is to separate them into 2 statements, defining the dataframe by pd.DataFrame first and then add column, as below.  But this will be in 2 statement and not sure whether you still count it as **"at the same time"**.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(), columns=['Summary','Count'])  # Your existing statement unchanged

df['my_list'] = my_list
```

Result:

```
print(df)


  Summary  Count  my_list
0     one    100       10
1     two    200       20
2   three    300       30
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Just to ensure im on a right way to explore we can do like this also ryt? 
       df['my_list'] = my_list     
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(), columns=['Summary','Count'])

Comment: You have to put `df['my_list'] = my_list` after the call to pd.DataFrame().   That's the most trivial way but in 2 statements.   As I seen you said at the same time, therefore I devised solution for you in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

This may also solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {'summary': ['one', 'two', 'three'],  'count': [100, 200, 300]}
my_list = [10,20,30]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
df['my_list'] = my_list
df.to_excel('df.xlsx')
```